# ionic 3 navController push same page issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, nav

I am using ionic3, and I have a typescript error below:

```
Individual declarations in merged declaration 'SearchPage' must be all exported or all local.
```

I am in SearchPage and have a tap function and it will push page , code below in search.ts:

```
this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage,{a:'1'});
```

How can I push a new page is the same page of the current page?

Comment: Can you post more code related to `SearchPage`?

Comment: You are importing SearchPage inside SearchPage?

Comment: @PareshGami yes I just figure it out. Thanks for your helping

Comment: Can you please post here what is reason so other developer can get help if same issue happens. Thanks

Comment: @PareshGami Sorry for the leak of information. And I figure it out the problem is importing SearchPage as you said. Now problem solved, thanks a lot.